# C#:SerialPort: read and write buffer size

Tags: c#

I am writing a program to send and receive data via a serial port with C#.

Although I have read this reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize.aspx, I am not quite clear if I change the values of the buffer for reading and writing:

```
serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 1; // or 1024 ?
serialPort.WriteBufferSize = 1;// or 1024 ?
```

The values (1 or 1024) should be better to be smaller or bigger?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't understand what something is, don't change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you provided states:

> **SerialPort.ReadBufferSize Property**
>
> The default value is 4096.
>
> The ReadBufferSize property ignores
> any value smaller than 4096.

It also states that setting an odd integer size throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest leaving the buffer sizes if you are only expecting your data to be a max of 1024.  If you were expecting to read/write data in excess of 4096, then you would need to adjust the buffer accordingly.